# Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'"

Tags: c#

I was doing this simple code snippet to generate the Month name by using the Day Number but I got the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'`. I'm not trying to change MonthName into int!

```
class Module04
{
    public static void Exercise01()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a day number between 1 and 365: ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        int dayNum = int.Parse(line);

        int monthNum = 0;

        if (dayNum <= 31) // January
        {
            goto End;
        }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 28) // February
        {
            goto End;
        }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 28;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // March
        {
            goto End;
        }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 30) // April
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 30;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // May
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 30) // June
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 30;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // July
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // August
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 30) // September
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 30;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // October
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 30) // November
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 30;
            monthNum++;
        }

        if (dayNum <= 31) // December
        { goto End; }
        else
        {
            dayNum -= 31;
            monthNum++;
        }

    End:

        string monthName;

        switch (monthName)
        {
            case 0:
                monthName = "January"; break;
            case 1:
                monthName = "February"; break;
            case 2:
                monthName = "March"; break;
            case 3:
                monthName = "April"; break;
            case 4:
                monthName = "May"; break;
            case 5:
                monthName = "June"; break;
            case 6:
                monthName = "July"; break;
            case 7:
                monthName = "August"; break;
            case 8:
                monthName = "September"; break;
            case 9:
                monthName = "October"; break;
            case 10:
                monthName = "November"; break;
            case 11:
                monthName = "December"; break;
            default:
                monthName = "Not yet Done"; break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dayNum, monthName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't account for leap years.

Comment: shouldn't this have the homework tag?

Comment: oopz.. ddnt knw abt it.. im a newbie over here.. il tag t 4 sure nxt ym:D

Answer (score 2):

It's the `switch` where you're using it as an int - You probably meant to pass `monthNum` to the switch statement.

(Also: Shouldn't you have `monthNum == ...` in all of the `if`s in the first part?)

Answer (score 1):

Change the switch to

```
switch (monthNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a switch on monthName, with int cases, thus c# try's to convert the string to int to match the cases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

monthName is a string so your switch cases should be a string also.

```
string monthName;

            switch (monthName)
            {
                case "0" :
                    monthName = "January"; break;
                case "1" :
                    monthName = "February"; break;
                case "2" :
                    monthName = "March"; break;
                case "3" :
                    monthName = "April"; break;
                case "4" :
                    monthName = "May"; break;
                case "5" :
                    monthName = "June"; break;
                case "6" :
                    monthName = "July"; break;
                case "7" :
                    monthName = "August"; break;
                case "8" :
                    monthName = "September"; break;
                case "9" :
                    monthName = "October"; break;
                case "10" :
                    monthName = "November"; break;
                case "11" :
                    monthName = "December"; break;
                default :
                    monthName = "Not yet Done"; break;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dayNum, monthName);
    }
```